# Modifying webpack in Next.js for static page

Tags: javascript, webpack, materialize, next.js

I am trying to use [Materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/) with my Next.js app by creating a static index.html page and importing the necessary files through the `head` tag in `index.html`.

My `index.html` contains the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I have created a `next.config.js` file with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev }) => {
      entry: './pages/index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
       }
    return config
  },
  webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
    // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config

    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  }
}
```

Upon running `npm run dev` I get the following error:

> output: 'bundle.js'
>
> ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

How do I edit this config file to create the `bundle.js` and serve my `index.js` into my `index.html`?

Comment: No need to configure that inside the Webpack config, Next.js takes care of that for you out of the box. You can use `next export` for exporting static sites. Read about [static export in Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#static-html-export).

Answer (score 0):

Next.js handle the bundle's entrypoint for you. If you need to edit che head of the html returned by your application, you have to edit the `_document.js` and add here the tags you need.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master#custom-document

Answer (score -1):

Your `next.config.js` seems to be wrong because you are treating it in part like an object when it is a function.
The first thing you should try is setting your properties of interest correctly

```
webpack: (config, { buildId, dev }) => {
    config.output.filename = 'bundle.js'; 

    // if you want to see the options you have you can just 
   console.log(config);

   return config
  }
```

If what you want is to just have a bundle for a static page just add 
`"export": "next build && next export"` to your `package.json` without altering the `next.config.js`(use their default). Run that and by default it will create a `out/_next` folder in the root of your project. Inside `_next` you will find your static `index.html` with the references to your code.